# getting error on including apex:inputfile in visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

i am getting error

> apex:inputFile can not be used in conjunction with an action
>   component, apex:commandButton or apex:commandLink that specifies a
>   rerender or oncomplete attribute.

but i cant skip using rerender or oncomplete.
how can i solve this.

```
<apex:actionRegion > 
  <apex:outputPanel id="Panel"> 
    <apex:repeat value="{!wrapperValues}" var="w"> 
      <apex:inputfile value="{!w.document}"/> 
    </apex:repeat> 
  </apex:outputPanel> 
  <apex:commandbutton style="width: 170px;" value="Add another" action="{!addAnother}" reRender="Panel" /> 
</apex:actionRegion>
```

Comment: can we use input type="file" instead of apex:inputfile

Comment: Please post some code. Help me help you. :-)

Comment: <apex:actionRegion >   <apex:outputPanel id="Panel">
    <apex:repeat value="{!wrapperValues}" var="w">
      <apex:inputfile value="{!w.document}"/>
    </apex:repeat>     </apex:outputPanel>           <apex:commandbutton style="width: 170px;"   value="Add another"
> action="{!addAnother}"   reRender="Panel"    />  </apex:actionRegion>

Comment: can we upload a file using html input type=file.if yes how we will bind it in backend

Comment: I copied your code from your comment into the question and added formatting.

Comment: thanks peter actually i was not getting how to paste it in a formatted way.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

As the error indicates, you simply can't do this.  I'd imagine its a security feature, as the inputFile is allowing uploading of a file from the user's computer.  You could use an iframe to contain the input file component, which means that other frames would be unaffected, but from the technical point of view it has to be a full refresh of the containing page.

Comment: hi bob.cant we use input type="file",HTML tag

Comment: No, as this will be regular HTML form rather than a Visualforce form, so the file won't be bound to anything on the controller side.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the inputfile component in a separate page and include the new page in your original page with an  component.